# mod_rewrite noobie question

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

So, i've got this Zend style frontcontroller set up. Basically it just redirects every url back to index.

The urls are in the form of /`controller/view/ + [additional parameters]`

I would like to create some shortcuts in the following form:

```
RewriteRule ^home /home/index
RewriteRule ^products /products/view

RewriteRule .* index.php
```

However, mod_rewrite seems to be ignoring my rewrite rules. It doesn't alter home to home/index, even though i'm fairly certain that it should be able to catch that bit. So, i'm thinking it has got something to do with renaming request uri?

Here's the .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule  ^admin/  -  [L]
RewriteRule  ^media/  -  [L]

RewriteRule  ^home        home/index
RewriteRule  ^products    products/view

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule .* index.php
```

Comment: Do the rules not work at all or is just the expected result wrong (*index.php* can’t handle it)? If the latter, what value does `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` contain?

Comment: $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] contains the original uri (home or products). It's like it's unable to alter the REQUEST_URI even though i'm sure that it's able to catch it. So by the time it reaches the last line that will redirect everything back to index.php, it treats it as it was unaltered.

Comment: Hmm, the REQUEST_URI should stay the same because you are rewriting and not redirecting. If you want the REQUEST_URI you can write a seperate line for that. You dont have the [L], which stands for Last Rule in your home and product line. This means that it will continue looking for any other matches. I've adjusted my answer.

Comment: @JHollanti: That seems to be the problem. Your frontcontroller uses `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` to get the requested URI, but that variable isn’t changed by an internal redirect. Only an external redirect (R flag) does that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far i've figured this much.

If you use the RewriteRule to alter your `REQUEST_URI` it doesn't actually alter `REQUEST_URI`, but another variable called `REDIRECT_URI`. That explains why nothng was happening.

Also, interestingly enough, i could do something like this:

```
RewriteRule ^products products/view [NC,L]
```

Something to this effect was was suggested by Fabian. He just appended index.php to the end, which didn't work for me. If i left that index.php out, everything worked perfectly. And somehow magically it redirects everything to index.php.

So for now, everything is working, but i haven't got a clue as to why everything is working. There's definitely an upvote for anyone who manages to explain what's happening here. Till then i think i'll just RTFM.

Answer (score 0):

The following rule catches everything, so if its at the top it will never consider any other rules.

```
RewriteRule .* index.php
```

Try the following

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule  ^admin/      -  [L]
RewriteRule  ^media/      -  [L]

RewriteRule  ^home        home/index [L]
RewriteRule  ^products    products/view [L]

RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule  .*           index.php
```

Comment: Yeah, the 'redirect everything to index' bit is located only in the end. sorry about that. Still doesn't work though..

Comment: Could you add your entire .htaccess file, alot easier that way.

Answer (score 0):

You might get problems when you try to rewrite everything that just begins with `/home` to `/home/index` as the latter does also begin with `/home`. You should use a more specific pattern like this:

```
RewriteRule ^home$ home/index
RewriteRule ^products$ products/view
```

But the rest should work fine.